# Symmetry about the plane in affine space

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry, affine-geometry

Let $H \subset \Bbb{R^3}$ be affine subspace defined by following equation:
$$x_1+2x_2-x_3=2$$
and $L$ is a line in $\Bbb{R^3}$ with parametric equation:
$$(0,1,1)+t(2,0,1)$$

Let $f:\Bbb{R^3}\to\Bbb{R^3}$ be a symmetry of the L about the $H$

Find the equation of $f(H_1)$, where $H_1$ is a plane also being set of solutions of following equation: $2x_1-x_2+x_3=1$

I don't even know where to start or what should I start with.
Any help and hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why L is given?

Comment: The symmetry concerns the line, didn't know how to write this down so I skipped this. Not sure if it's correct now but I think I fixed it

Comment: I can give a guide to solve but I don't understand what kind of symmetry it is "about H along L"?

Comment: Sorry, i totally don't know how to write that properly and while trying to translate, I'm copying every word hoping that it'll make any sense

Comment: Sorry but  don't understand what does it mean that $f$ is a symmetry of $L$ about $H$. Maybe a point on the line is reflected with respect to the plane?

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I wanted to say - the $H$ plane reflects the $L$ line

Comment: ah ok that meke sense it is a kind of oblique reflection with respect to the plane! It is not an easy case! I try to formulate a guide for the answer!

Comment: It’s still not clear to me how $L$ is relevant. Are you meant to reflect $H_1$ in the *point* at which $L$ intersects $H$?

Comment: @amd is it possible that each point is reflected about the plane parallel to line L and not ortoginally?

Comment: @gimusi :shrug: Perhaps if I saw the relevant part of the question in its original language...

Comment: @amd Do you want try to write down a solution? Otherwise I will try

Comment: @gimusi I can see four plausible solutions right now, one for each interpretation that I’ve got of the required reflection, but the construction method for all of them is similar.

Comment: @amd my idea was to translate $H\to H_0$ through the origin, write the reflection with respect to a basis with $v_1,v_2 \in H_0$ and $v_3\parallel L$ then change basis to the canonical and then translate of $-v_0$.

Comment: @amd I've tried to give an hint? Do you think it can work? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi That’s certainly the way I’d construct the oblique reflection, but then I’d calculate the reflected plane directly. In homogeneous coordinates, planes in $\mathbb P^3$ transform as $\mathbf\pi' = M^{-T}\mathbf\pi$ which becomes $R^T\mathbf\pi$ for a reflection.

Comment: @amd I'm not aware about homogeneous coordinates at the moment :(

Comment: @Igor Did you succeed with the solution?

Comment: @gimusi yes, what I had to was to find point of intersection of the line and the plane and, knowing that every point from the plane is mapped into itself and every vector from line to the plane is mapped into minus itself, I've found a equation for the symmetry.

Comment: @Igor Well done, but did you follow my hint or you did it by another way?

Comment: The way I did it was shown to me by my mate but it looks that both of these ways are very similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

To construct the matrix for $f$ let proceed as follow

1. Translate $H\to H_0$ through the origin by $v_0=\left(-\frac13,-\frac23,\frac13\right)$

$$H_0: x_1+2x_2-x_3=0$$

2. Consider a basis with $v_1,v_2 \in H_0$ and $v_3\parallel L$ that is

$$v_1=(1,0,1)\quad v_2=(2,-1,0)\quad v_3=(2,0,1)$$

3. The symmetry matrix in this basis is

$$S_0=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

4. The matrix for the change of basis form the given basis to the standard basis is

$$M=[v_1\,v_2\,v_3]=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\0&-1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

5. The symmetry matrix in the standard basis is

$$R_0=MS_0M^{-1}$$

6. Then $w=f(v)$ is represented by

$$w=R_0v-v_0$$

7. Find a basis for $H_1$

$$w_1=(1,2,0)\quad w_2=(0,1,1)\quad w_0=\left(\frac26,-\frac16,\frac16\right)$$

$$P\in H_1: aw_1+bw_2+w_0$$

8. Compute $f(w_1)$, $f(w_2)$ and $f(w_0)$ to find the image of $H_1$.

Comment: could you explain how did you find that $u_0=(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3})$  ??

Comment: @giannispapav We are looking for $v_0 \parallel n=(1,2,-1)$ that is $v_0=k(1,2,-1)$ such that, form H equation, $k+4k+k=-2\implies  k=-\frac13$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It’s still not entirely clear to me *which* of the possible reflections (symmetries) you’re meant to compute, so I’ll sketch out the overall construction methods.

All of the symmetries leave the intersection of $L$ and $H$ fixed, so let’s start by computing that. I like working in homogeneous coordinates for problems like this. $L$ is the join of the points $\mathbf l_0 = [2:0:1:0]$ and $\mathbf l_1 = [0:1:1:1]$, and $\mathbf H = [1:2:-1:-2]$, so their intersection is $$\mathbf p = \mathbf l_0\mathbf l_1^T\mathbf H-\mathbf l_1\mathbf l_0^T\mathbf H = [-2:-1:-2:-1],$$ which corresponds to the inhomogeneous coordinates $\tilde{\mathbf p} = (2,1,2)^T$.

The homogeneous vectors that represent planes are covariant: if we have a point transformation matrix $\mathbf x' = M\mathbf x$, then planes transform as $\mathbf\pi'=M^{-T}\mathbf\pi.$ We’re working with reflections, which are their own inverses, so once we have the point reflection matrix $R$, the reflection of the plane $\mathbf H_1$ Is $R^T\mathbf H_1$.

The reflection will be a bit easier to construct if we decompose it as a translation of $\mathbf p$ to the origin, a reflection of some sort that leaves the origin fixed, and then a translation back, i.e., $R=T_{\mathbf p}R_OT_{-\mathbf p}$. This might seem like a lot of matrix multiplication at first glance, but it’s not. In block form, $$T_{\mathbf p}R_OT_{-\mathbf p} = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}I_3 & \tilde{\mathbf p} \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c|c}R_3 & \mathbf 0 \\ \hline  \mathbf 0^T & 1 \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c|c}I_3 & -\tilde{\mathbf p} \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}R_3 & (I_3-R_3)\tilde{\mathbf p} \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1 \end{array}\right].$$ Here, $R_3$ is a $3\times3$ reflection matrix.

All that’s left to do is to compute $R_3$, and that’s where we need to know exactly which reflection it is that is being computed. If it’s a reflection in the point $\mathbf p$, then $R_3=-I_3$. If it’s the usual orthogonal reflection in some plane, then you can use the standard formula $I-2{\tilde{\mathbf n}\tilde{\mathbf n}^T\over\tilde{\mathbf n}^T\tilde{\mathbf n}}$, where $\tilde{\mathbf n}$ is a (inhomogeneous) 3-d vector normal to the plane. If it’s the oblique reflection that gimusi suggests, then a way to construct it is to find a basis in which the matrix of the reflection is $\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1)$ and perform a change of basis back to the standard basis. For the first vector in this basis, take $L$’s direction vector $(2,0,1)^T$. For the remaining two vectors, you need a linearly-independent pair of vectors parallel to $H$. $H$’s normal is $(1,2,-1)^T$. We can immediately read from it three vectors orthogonal to it: $(0,1,2)^T$, $(1,0,1)^T$ and $(2,-1,0)^T$. They’re obviously pairwise linearly independent, so any two of them will do. Taking the first two, we’d have $$R_3 = \begin{bmatrix}2&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$ The resulting matrix $R_3$ will end up being the same regardless of the choice.

Comment: I suppose that I should mention that the components of the homogeneous vector that represents a plane are just the coefficients of the plane’s implicit Cartesian equation, i.e., $ax+by+cz+d=0$ corresponds to $[a:b:c:d]$, and so $\mathbf x$ lies on the plane $\mathbf\pi$ iff $\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf x=0$.

Comment: I had to upovote on faith since I'm sure that's a good solution!